# How to use the same ViewModel for different Pages (views)

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, view, viewmodel, caliburn.micro

I am searching for a way to use one `ViewModel` for two different `Views (Pages)`. I know there is [Multi-view support](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View/ViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions&ANCHOR) in `Caliburn.Micro` and I read a lot of it but I'm not sure if it is what I am looking for or how it works on Windows Phone.

Currently, I have one View `ItemPage.xaml` and one ViewModel `ItemPageViewModel`. I use this View/ViewModel to add a new Item and display an existing Item. Depending on the mode (add, show, ...) I need to show/hide or enable/disable some UI elements and display different AppBar buttons. 
Instead of control these UI elements by binding to properties, I want to create two seperate Pages(Views) with the corrrect UI elements.

It would be nice to use the same `ViewModel` for both `Pages` to avoid repitive code. So is my use-case above possible with `Caliburn.Micro` for Windows Phone?

Comment: The answer really depends quite a bit on where the view is being "hosted" and if it's view first or view model first. Can you expand a bit on that?

Comment: @NigelSampson What do you mean with "hosted"? I think it is ViewModel first because I use `navigationService.UriFor<ItemPageViewModel>().Navigate();` to navigate.

Comment: A problem this approach is that you're asking CM to navigate to the view for a given view model but then wanting that view model to have two different views, how would CM know which VM you mean?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the meaining of Multi-view. I thought this means to have different Views (in case of WP: Pages) for one ViewModel.

Comment: It can be done with CM with some caveats, you need to provide a "context" to the view locator, which currently isn't possible with navigation service.